# Laravel vs Symfony | Model Attributes

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, eloquent, orm

I'm actually discovering Laravel (I've used symfony for years) and I face a situation where I don't know if I just couldn't find the right information or it is just the way to do in Laravel.

When creating a model in Symfony you put attributes in your model class. Actually these attributes represent the different columns of your table for the ORM.

Now in Laravel I see all people don't put theses attributes in the model class but in the migrations files. So a new developer who should contribute in a new project will have to look on database or migrations files. Which in my opinion is not the rule of an ORM : "**let dev think class and not table**"

Could somebody, please, put a light on this point?

Thanks

Comment: While this could be an interesting discussion, this sort of opinion based question is completely off-topic for Stack Overflow.  On the other hand, if a developer is supposed to be thinking class then why put database information in the class itself?

Comment: This is due to the difference of approach from Doctrine and Eloquent ORM. Doctrine is a Data Mapper ORM where your properties match the column in db while Eloquent is an Active Record one. In Eloquent your fields comes directly from the database.

Comment: Some prefer to use `@property` docblocks on their Eloquent models to show and type hint which attributes a model contains

Answer (score 2):

If you use PHPStorm (but it can work with other IDEs as well) there is an interesting composer package that can generate model documentation for you, in order to have autocompletion for attributes ad methods based on your migrations:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

its three main methods:

- `php artisan ide-helper:generate` creates phpDoc for Facades
- `php artisan ide-helper:model` creates phpDoc for your model (you should relaunch it after every new migration)
- `php artisan ide-helper:meta` creates phpstorm meta file

so, if you launch php artisan ide-helper:model it will add something similar to this

```
/**
 * App\User
 *
 * @property-read \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission[] $permissions
 * @property-read \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Spatie\Permission\Models\Role[] $roles
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User permission($permissions)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User role($roles, $guard = null)
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $email
 * @property \Illuminate\Support\Carbon|null $email_verified_at
 * @property string $password
 * @property string|null $remember_token
 * @property \Illuminate\Support\Carbon|null $created_at
 * @property \Illuminate\Support\Carbon|null $updated_at
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User whereCreatedAt($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User whereEmail($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User whereEmailVerifiedAt($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User whereId($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User whereName($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User wherePassword($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User whereRememberToken($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\User whereUpdatedAt($value)
 * [...]
 */
```

So you have a phpDoc

and your IDE should be able to autocomplete your code like this:

[image]